# Error installing WMVare Tools

Tags: vmware, esxi

Good afternoon! Colleagues, tell me please the answer to this problem, I installed a new virtual machine on the test bench with CentOS 7, I try to install VMware Tools, and get a usr/bin/perl bad error.
On [one site](http://pyatilistnik.org/usr-bin-perl-bad-interpreter/) I found a similar case, and there a person installed the perl package.
yum install perl
I seem to have installed it, but still get this error, can there be any dependencies yet?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's worth checking the following site for some detailed instructions on installing VMware Tools onto CentOS7: http://partnerweb.vmware.com/GOSIG/CentOS_7.html#Tools